# What are all the possible right and left inverses for $f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define a function $f:ℕ→ℕ$ by $f(n)=n-1$  for $n≥2$, and $f(1)=30$. What are all possible right  and left inverses for f?

My intuition tells me that it has to do with injectivity and surjectivity. But I have problem figuring it out.

Comment: Hint: write down the conditions $(l \circ f)(n) = n$ (resp. $(f \circ r)(n) = n$_ for a left (resp. right) inverse of $f$ and then try to solve the equations using the definition of $f$ to find out what $l$ and $r$ would have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $f(31)=f(1)=30$, so the function is not injective. However, the function is surjective (onto) because we can have $f(k+1)=k$.

A left inverse $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ would be such that $g(f(n))=n$. Should such a function exist, then $g(f(31))=31$ and $g(f(1))=1$, but by the remark above $g(f(31))=g(f(1))$. So NO left inverse can exist.

A **right inverse** $h:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ would be such that $f(h(n))=n$. Can you try the right inverse now?

Comment: Hi, I understand that f is surjective, therefore left inverse definitely exists. However, does this mean that there exists infinite number of h(n)? For sure that h(n) = n+1 is a right inverse, but I am confused about whether it is unique or not.

Comment: @JanetWang you mean surjective implies **right inverse exists**. For uniqueness, say there exists $k$ which is also a right inverse of $f$, then $f(g(n))=f(k(n))$ for all $n$. This implies $g(n)-1=k(n)-1$ for all $n$. Consequently, $g$ and $k$ are same functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question, if we find the right inverse $h$ of $f$, then f becomes the left inverse of h. How do we know how many left inverses are  there for h? By checking its bijectivity first?